# Where to find a real-life example of a Maven plugin for maven-plugin-api 3.0?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-3

Where can I find a complete example of a Maven plugin written for maven-plugin-api 3.0? Preferably with unit and integration tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [maven-site-plugin](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/plugins/branches/maven-site-plugin-3.x/) for maven 3. This plugin is now using maven 3 API.